# Spring MVC Abstract Controller PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, abstract-class

I've an abstract controller and have path variables in some of it's operations:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/generic-status/v1")
public abstract class GenericStatusController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/connection/availability/{connectionName}", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public abstract ConnectionResult checkConnection( @PathVariable("connectionName") String connectionName ) throws ConnectionException, ParameterInvalidException, StatusApiException;
```

When I extend and use it all request mappings are working properly. But unfortunately path variable always come as null.

Could you please help me in this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You still need `@PathVariable` in your overridden method...

Comment: Thank you but I don't want overriden method to specify this path variable :S Is there any other way ?

Comment: You have an abstract method, annotations on method arguments aren't inherited so no you don't have another way, unless you implement this method in the abstract method and handoff to an other method from that, but that doesn't make things prettier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As M.Deinum pointed out:
From what ive deducted after extending this abstract controller you have something like this:

```
@Override
ConnectionResult checkConnection(String connectionName) throws ConnectionException, ParameterInvalidException, StatusApiException; {
     // logic
}
```

Which means that the instance of controller you will be using has actually no @PathVariable mapping describing and telling Spring it should provide it as an argument to the method.
Solution: Add @PathVariable also in extending controller:

```
@Override
ConnectionResult checkConnection(@PathVariable("connectionName") String connectionName) throws ConnectionException, ParameterInvalidException, StatusApiException; {
     // logic
}
```

Comment: Thank  you but I don't want overriden method to specify this path variable :S Is there any other way ?

Comment: Edit. Overriding this method without @PathVariable you said that you want to change it's normal behaviour. To preserve it annotation has to be used again. It seems pretty normal.